# QGIS plugin to find the common center for a series of nested circles

Tags: qgis

I am looking for a QGIS plugin that will find the common center for a series on nested circles. This would be something like the old game tracker program written by the biological division on the United States Geological Survey.  Esri has software that will do this but it is horrendously expensive.

Comment: You may not need a plugin. It is likely you can achieve this with a virtual layer or a geometry expression. Could you add a screenshot / diagram illustrating what you are aiming for?